# Fetching Collection when you don't know the ID of the Document before it

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore is structured like;

Collection ("User") -> Document ("Uid") -> Collection ("programme") -> Document ("Session-One, Session-Two, Session-Three...") -> Collection ("exercises") -> Document(".. a few documents with exercises").

I need to get to the exercises collection where I display all the exercises a user has for a specific session. But I only want to show a certain session if it matches the date in a field to the current date of day. So I don't actually know the id of the .document id before exercises.

Ive tried to fetch the document id and pass into a new fetch using the id grabbed but it crashed.

I also need to rewrite the whole session to a history collection. Now the id can be viewed on screen, but when I try pass the id into a function where it can be written to firestore it saves as "String". How can I get the doc ID of sessions where the date field matches the current date and then use that to fetch exercises.

The current code is the basic fetch function I tried to use await to get the id first but I was unable to pass that id through to the next fetch.

```
struct Training: Identifiable, Codable {
       
        @DocumentID var Docid: String? = UUID().uuidString
        var id: String
        var name: String
        var date: String
    }

class TrainingsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var trainings = [Training]()
    
    var date = Date()
    var today : String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM"
        return formatter.string(from: date)
    }
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchTrainingData() {
        
        let trainingRef = db.collection("uuid").document(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "").collection("programme").whereField("date", isEqualTo: "\(today)")
        trainingRef.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print ("No Documents")
                return
            }
            
            self.trainings = documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Training? in
                
                return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Training.self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]